# What is the best way for concurrent data collection in Go, and why?

Tags: go, concurrency, goroutine

There are two ways to collect data that I have found in practice. My colleagues use different ways. However, most projects on github (for example, vault) use the second way. I can't decide which one is better. Can you explain why one way or another is better than the other?

Code: https://play.golang.org/p/OKV7pAwyGuQ

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

// complex request
func getData() string {
    return "test"
}

func main() {
    // first way
    var wg1 sync.WaitGroup
    var mu1 sync.Mutex
    res1 := make([]string, 0, 10)
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        wg1.Add(1)
        go func(wg *sync.WaitGroup, mu *sync.Mutex) {
            defer wg.Done()

            mu.Lock()
            res1 = append(res1, getData())
            mu.Unlock()

        }(&wg1, &mu1)
    }

    wg1.Wait()
    fmt.Println(res1)

    // second way
    var wg2 sync.WaitGroup
    ch := make(chan string, 10)
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        wg2.Add(1)
        go func(wg *sync.WaitGroup, ch chan string) {
            defer wg.Done()

            ch <- getData()
        }(&wg2, ch)
    }

    wg2.Wait()
    close(ch)

    res2 := make([]string, 0, 10)
    for data := range ch {
        res2 = append(res2, data)
    }

    fmt.Println(res2)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your question is that the usage of the term "better" requires a set of criteria which are used to make the comparison. In day-to-day life such sets of criteria are often implied and are shared by the communicating people so the term "better" used alone is OK. (But even then, when you hear, say, "this car is better than that car"—are you sure whoever speaks is sharing the same wordview on cars that you do? Or let's consider the statement "Python is better than Go"—it implies the response "Better for what task exactly?".)
In engeneering, asking "what's better" requires a rigorous defintion of what criteria the asker has in mind, and your question has none; basically that's why it gets downvoted.

If we consider your two examples, they are mostly identical, and the differences can be summarized as such:

- The first updates the resulting data structure in place, protecting the operation by an explicit lock.
- The second buffers the data in an intermediate data structure using an implicit lock, and once the data is collected, it is copied into the resulting data structure.

Which one is better, again?

If we consider readability and the cost of maintenance, the former has less line count but it has an explicit lock manipulation which sometimes is frowned upon¹.
The latter has greater line count and supposedly has greater WTF-factor (because the reader might get puzzled about the usage of seemingly unnecessary buffering—see below).

If we consider performance, I would speculate the former approach will win (by a small margin).
The reason is that accessing a channel form multiple goroutines does use synchronization—though it's hidden in whatever runtime code which gets compiled in in place of those `<-` and `->` operations, and I'd not expect the contention on a channel to spend less CPU cycles than the contention on a mutex.
Then consider that after all the collecting goroutines are done, in the second case you're left with the data placed in a buffered channel which you then shovel into the resulting slice—that's a (step-by-step) memory copy mixed with channel accesses—which will be fast in the uncontended case but still each channel access *must* make sure there are no contenders and "lock" and then "unlock" the channel's internal structure during the read operation, and also update the channel's length on each step.

Then again: if we're talking about 10 pieces of data of the type which is cheap to copy, the performance difference would be miniscule, and I'd pick whatever reads best.
But if it's really a model example, and in the production code that will be 100k of data units, or 1e6 pieces of data, things will look differently.

On a side note, please consider that in the first example calling `getData()` while holding the lock would supposedly not pass code review.

---

**TL;DR**
Prefer readability over performance when performance does not look like a problem.
Otherwise [measure](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#B).
When preferring readability, [still mind performance](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2021/02/16/arranging-invisible-icons-in-quadratic-time/).

---

¹ That is because if some code called after the lock is taken, panics, the lock might be left held; consider:

```golang
s.mu.Lock()
res = append(res, fooBar())
s.mu.Unlock()
```

Here, if `fooBar()` panics, the `s.mu.Unlock()` won't be called.
Obviously, this can be worked around by factoring out the whole thing into a helper function, and deferring there the mutex unlocking statement.
Better yet, in this very code it's possibly the best to split obtaining the value to `append` and the `append`ing itself: since `append` cannot crash (well, except if it fails to allocate memory, but in a Go program that would be a *hard* crash), it's safe to just wrap it in such lock+unlock combo.
And still yet, some people would consider this as a no-go as *someone could possibly want to add more code between the lock and unlock statements* and then we're back at square one.